# Why is R not calculating values for the standard error function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, na

I would like to calculate the standard error of the mean for a dataset that includes NA and groupings.  I have included na.rm = TRUE, but R still won't calculate the standard error

I have created a standard error function

```
se <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE){
  sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
 }
```

and calculated the mean and standard error for my data after grouping by col_1.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(col_1 = c("a", "a","a","B", "B","B","C", "C", "C"),
                 col_2 = c(2, 5, 3, NA, NA, NA, 5, 8, NA))

mean <- df %>%
  group_by(col_1)%>%
  summarise(mean = mean(col_2, na.rm = TRUE))

std.err <- df %>%
  group_by(col_1) %>%
  summarise(std.err = se(col_2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The mean works as expected.  I get a result for groups A and C, but not group B because it is entirely NA.  However, the std.err provides NA for both groups B and C.  How do I get R to calculate the standard error for group C?

Comment: Just place `na.rm = TRUE` within `sd()` call: `sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Such an easy fix.  Thank you!

Comment: Consider using `se` = `sd(x) / sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))`, as `NA`-values should not count towards the standard error when you want to use `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I caught that as well after posting this yesterday.